# C program not entering any for loops?

Tags: c, arrays, function, scope, pass-by-pointer

**THIS IS A HOMEWORK ASSIGNMENT**

My program seems to not be entering any for loops at all. At one point I had every function in `main` and was operating on 2 global variables without having to pass by reference or by value and everything was working correctly. Since then I have moved my functions out of `main` and am passing an array by reference and the length of that array into each function, I am getting `printf` statements that are outside of loops but nothing executes other than that.

According to GDB my program exits with exit code `046`.

The program is simple, it takes a value to set as the length of my array and then prompts the user for integer values to fill that array. I then sort the array, thent I print the array, and finally I call `getMax(int *array, int n)` to print the largest value to the screen.

An example of output is:

```
Enter the number of elements to be sorted:
3
Enter 10 integers in any order:
2
1
4
Inside sortArray
Inside sort and print
inside setMAx
The largest value in the array is: 0
```

I seem to have broke something, I should of never messed with it. Here is my attempt.

Thank you for any assistance, I'll be sitting here trying to find my bug.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray (int *array, int n);
void sortArray (int *array, int n);
void fillArray (int *array, int n);
void getMax (int *array, int n);

int main(void){

    int array[10],n = 0;

    fillArray  (array, n);
    sortArray  (array, n);
    printArray (array, n);
    getMax     (array, n);

    return 0;
}

void sortArray(int *array,int n){
   printf("Inside sortArray\n");

   int temp, c = 0, c2;
   for(c=0;c<n;c++){
        printf("inside for loop SA\n");
        for(c2=c;c2<n;c2++){ 
            if(array[c]>array[c2]){
            temp=array[c];
            array[c]=array[c2];
            array[c2]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArray (int *array, int n){
    int c = 0;
    printf("Inside sort and print\n");
    for(c=0;c<n;c++){
            printf("\t%d",array[c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void fillArray (int *array, int n){
    int c = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter 10 integers in any order: \n");
    for(c=0;c<n;c++){
        scanf("%d", &array[c]);
    }
}

void getMax (int *array, int n){
    printf("inside setMax\n");
    int temp = 0, i = 0;

    for (i = 0;i<n;i++){
        printf("temp: %d", temp);
        if(array[i]>temp)
        temp=array[i];
    }    
    printf("\nThe largest value in the array is: %d\n", temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void fillArray (int *array, int n)` doesn't update the value of `n`. You should pass `n` as a  pointer, giving `fillArray` the following signature: `void fillArray (int *array, int *n)`.

Then, inside `fillArray`, you would use `*n` to modify it's value or `n` instead of `&n`.

Lastly, when calling `fillArray`, you'll call it with `&n`.

Comment: Or return the value for `n` in a `return` statement, and change the type of the `fillArry()` function so it returns an `int`.

Comment: Both of these answers helped me, but I had another problem and reading this answer again fixed that for me as well, so this is the one I picked. Thanks everyone! I have fixed it successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Pass address of `n` to `fillArray()` function so that in `main()` you get number of elements user wants to enter.

Call it as

```
fillArray  (array, &n);
```

Define it as

```
void fillArray (int *array, int *ptr_n){
    int c = 0, n =0;
    printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter 10 integers in any order: \n");
    for(c=0;c<n;c++){
        scanf("%d", &array[c]);
    }
    //set ptr_n
    *ptr_n = n;
}
```

---

You can also return `n` from `fillArray()` instead of passing pointer for it.

```
n = fillArray  (array, n);
```

Define it as

```
int fillArray (int *array, int n){
    int c = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter 10 integers in any order: \n");
    for(c=0;c<n;c++){
        scanf("%d", &array[c]);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You path `n` by value to `fillArray`, and simply init locall copy of `n` with `0`, so when you exit the function, your `n` remains `0` in main function. You shold path `n` by refernce

```
  void fillarray(.... int* n)
  {

       ....
       scanf("%d",n);
  }
```

or even better simply return n from `fillarray`

```
  n = fillarray(int *array)
```

Answer (score 1):

your passing n in the main function to all other function which is initialized to 0 . so none of the loop are working since when you check it with n it fails and comes out of the loop.

variables declared inside the function(including declared as parameter variable) is local to that function alone.

your reading the value n in `fillArray` in which is valid only till the function is in scope. 
it wont be reflected back to main function n(both are different variable).

you either can read the value of n in the main program then pass it other function.

if you have understanding of the pointer concept you can use to that in `fillArray` so the n reflects back in main.

`void fillArray (int *array, int *n)`

in main

`fillArray  (array, &n);`

and also while reading in scanf use `n` not `&n` and in for loop `*n`